# How to fade background image so links/text is visible?

Tags: javascript, text, mouseover, fadeout

What I'm trying to achieve is to have an image fade upon mouseover so that text is visible - the image is (eg) a cd cover, and when the mouse-pointer is placed over the image, it should fade to show the track listing of the album. Each track listing is a hyperlink to the track on youtube.

I've zero experience of jquery, so am hoping to do this with javascript.

I'd be very appreciative of any help, as I've spent about two days now trying to google an answer.

Comment: I'd really recommend you learn jquery, it's very easy and painless. It also handles animations very easily.

Answer (score 0):

If under "fade" you mean animation, try this:

```
function SetObjectOpacity(obj, op, op100)
{
    obj.style.opacity = op.toString();
    obj.style["-moz-opacity"] = op.toString();
    obj.style["filter"] = "alpha(opacity=" + op100 + ")";
}

function FadeImage(imageid)
{
    var framedelay = 50;
    var frame = 0, img = document.getElementById(imageid), animint;
    animint = setInterval(function() {
        frame++;
        SetObjectOpacity(img, frame / 20, frame * 5);
        if (frame == 20) {
            img.style.visibility = 'hidden';
            clearInterval(animint);
        }
    }, framedelay);
}
```

And in HTML code:

```
<div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; position: relative;">
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 200px; height: 200px;">
        text you want to show
    </div>
    <img src="yourimage.jpg" id="yourimage" onMouseOver="FadeImage('yourimage');" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;">
</div>
```

Fading back on mouse out is obvious.

Answer (score 0):

I really do recommend you use jQuery—it makes everything so much easier. And it's not really difficult. After all, we have the code ready for you (and I would be glad to explain it further), so all you need to do is include it.

So, assuming you go with jQuery, try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/e2E5z/):

```
$(".overlay").hover(function(){
    $(this).stop().fadeTo(300,0.8);   
},function(){
    $(this).stop().fadeTo(300,0);
});
```

And here's your HTML/CSS:

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200/200" />
    <div class="overlay">
        <a href="#">Hi</a><br>
        <a href="#">Hi</a><br>
        <a href="#">Hi</a><br>
    </div>
</div>

.overlay {
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:-205px;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:black;
    opacity:0;
}
```

Comment: OP said he wanted to avoid jQuery, in favor of a pure JS solution. Read the question.

Comment: @Truth: I did, but I posted this to recommend jQuery to the OP. As in, part of the answer is the recommendation to use jQuery. He really should go the easy route--we have the code ready for him, he just has to include it. If necessary I could explain what everything does.

Comment: Hey Purmou, thanks for the jQuery tip - am quickly going through a tutorial on the net to see if I can get my head around it (I've only a few days left to submit this for college, so time is not my friend!) I didn't want to be "that guy" who asks a question, and is never heard from again, so thanks all for your replies - I'll let you know how I got on.

Comment: Sorry Purmou, could you tell me what I should be typing instead of "this"? Thanks.

Comment: @Brendan: `$(this)` is a valid jQuery selector--what it does is select the currently selected element (so, in this case, it selects elements with the class `overlay`. Have you checked my jsfiddle?